# Where does the HotSpot JVM store interpreted bytecode?

Tags: java, jvm, jit, jvm-hotspot

I've been wondering where interpreted byte-code of methods are stored internally in the JVM (specifically HotSpot x64). I know that methods that are JIT-ed are stored and can be accessed in the [Method](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/d19a396e96cee4bb4facb268c723f23cbae83351/src/hotspot/share/oops/method.hpp) structure but I'm trying to understand where the JVM stores the byte-code converted to assembly instructions (I assume it stores them, otherwise there would be a lot of memory usage to interpret every invocation) as I wasn't able to find it in the internals source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpreting bytecode is not as expensive as you would think. Why would the JVM spend time generating machine code for code that runs once? Best to wait until a certain method or block reaches the JIT threshold and only *then* spend time enabling the tracing JIT.

The `src/share/vm/interpreter` subdirectory seems to be what you're after:

- `bytecodeInterpreter.cpp` implements the actual stack machine;
- `bytecodes.cpp` defines the shape and attributes of each opcode.
- `bytecodes.h` declares all bytecodes.
- `templateTable.cpp` contains machinery to map JVM opcodes to assembly.
- `cpu/*/vm/templateTable*.cpp` contains the actual code to generate assembly snippets for the given CPU.

Comment: Maybe you could point me to where the JVM executes the interpreted byte-code of a method? As that's what I'm more interested in finding.

Comment: Another question: is there a place the JVM stores the assembly of the interpreted byte-codes of a method?

Comment: Perhaps you should dig a bit on your own. At a guess I would start looking at (the subclasses of) Method.

Comment: @aruhn an interpreter doesn’t store assembly instructions. A compiler does. That’s the fundamental difference between an interpreter and a compiler.

Comment: Rereading the question, I see you have misunderstood my answer. The interpreter does not store any assembly, it simply interprets the opcodes and modifies the stack and heap.

Comment: So a method that hasn’t reached enough invocations to have been compiled gets its opcodes interpreted and executed on the fly for every invocation?

Comment: Correct. That is what the byte code interpreter does. Again, it is not as expensive as you think it is.